# Hadoop.1.0.3 is not working anymore

Tags: hadoop

I'm working with hadoop.1.0.3. Everything was fine but since this morning I can't run my programs anymore.
For example to run WordCount sample I use this script:

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar *.java
rm -f wordcount.jar
jar cvf wordcount.jar *.class
chmod 777 wordcount.jar
rm -f output*.txt

hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /path/to/path/input.txt /user/path/input.txt

hadoop jar wordcount.jar WordCount WordCount/input.txt output/outputWordCount

rm -f output.txt

hadoop fs -cat 'output/outputWordCount/part-*' > output.txt
hadoop dfs -rmr /user/mahnaz/output
more output.txt
```

After starting the hadoop I run this .sh file and get this result:

```
$ sh run.sh
added manifest
adding: WordCount$Map.class(in = 1918) (out= 796)(deflated 58%)
adding: WordCount$Reduce.class(in = 1591) (out= 642)(deflated 59%)
adding: WordCount.class(in = 1516) (out= 743)(deflated 50%)
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

copyFromLocal: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create file/path/inputEdgeCount/edge.txt. Name node is in safe mode.
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
```

Actually after this last warning, program wont have any progress and I have to exit by `ctrl+c`

Do you have any idea that what is it's problem and what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your HDFS system is still starting up, if you have successfully used it before, otherwise could mean corruption or other problems with your HDFS.

If you believe everything is alright, you could try to force the node to leave the safe mode:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Comment: what do you mean still starting up? this is the result of jps command: 5363 SecondaryNameNode
5117 DataNode
5447 JobTracker
5684 TaskTracker
6881 Jps
4873 NameNode
It doesn't mean that hadoop is up?

Comment: @AshKan Usually it could take a couple of minutes to start up, after starting the nodes.